# mysql/mariadb trigger problem on different tables on Debian 11 and 12

Tags: triggers, mariadb, locking

I simplify my problem, so anybody can test it.

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `_trigger_test` (
  `rowid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rowid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;


CREATE TABLE `_trigger_test_log` (
  `rowid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `original_rowid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `action` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ts` datetime NOT NULL,
  `new_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rowid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

With these triggers:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_delete`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `_trigger_test`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO _trigger_test_log (original_rowid, action, ts, new_value) VALUES (OLD.rowid, 'AFTER DELETE', NOW(), OLD.name)
//
DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_insert`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `_trigger_test`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO _trigger_test_log (original_rowid, action, ts, new_value) VALUES (NEW.rowid, 'AFTER INSERT', NOW(), NEW.name)
//
DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_update`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `_trigger_test`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO _trigger_test_log (original_rowid, action, ts, new_value) VALUES (NEW.rowid, 'AFTER UPDATE', NOW(), NEW.name)
//
DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `before_delete`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `before_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON `_trigger_test`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO _trigger_test_log (original_rowid, action, ts, new_value) VALUES (OLD.rowid, 'BEFORE DELETE', NOW(), OLD.name)
//
DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `before_insert`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `_trigger_test`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO _trigger_test_log (original_rowid, action, ts, new_value) VALUES (NEW.rowid, 'BEFORE INSERT', NOW(), NEW.name)
//
DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `before_update`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `_trigger_test`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO _trigger_test_log (original_rowid, action, ts, new_value) VALUES (OLD.rowid, 'BEFORE UPDATE', NOW(), OLD.name)
//
DELIMITER ;
```

When I create these I can do anything without problem. But after a while or after I restart the sql server I get this error, which is nonsense in this case:

```
#1442 - Can't update table '_trigger_test_log' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

The commands are:

```
LOCK TABLES _trigger_test WRITE;
INSERT INTO _trigger_test (name) VALUES ('James');
UPDATE _trigger_test SET name = 'John' WHERE name = 'James';
DELETE FROM _trigger_test WHERE name = 'John';
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Without the LOCK TABLES it works, but it needs in my production environment because I do much more.

MariaDB use implicit locks, if I add _trigger_test_log WRITE to LOCK TABLES it works most of the time, but after 1 or 2 hundred execution it fails. According to documentation it should work without that. (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/triggers-and-implicit-locks/)

It works under Ubuntu 10.04, 14.04, 18.04, 22.04, Debian 10. The problem appears in Debian 11 and Debian 12.
MariaDB versions: 10.11.4-1~deb12u1 and 10.5.19-0+deb11u2

Please help me to solve this problem!

Thank you in advance, Tamas

I expect to execute these commands without any error message as older versions do.

Comment: Any other missing triggers ? Please switch to InnoDB if possible

Comment: Possibly related to [this bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30163). Using InnoDB and more granular locking (`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` with index on `name`) should avoid this bug, but I was unable to replicate, so cannot confirm. Unrelated, but if you want to use UTF-8 you should _probably_ be using `utf8mb4`, not the old `utf8mb3`.

Comment: There are no other triggers.